# gcc to link manually failed: cannot find some symbols of my runtime library

Tags: object, gcc, linker, resolve, manual

I was trying this on my 64 bit ubuntu:

First I've got a simple program

```
$ cat test.c
int f(int x){
        int i=(x/42);
        return i;
}
int main(){
        return 0;
}
```

Then I manually specify how it's linked:

```
$ gcc test.c -nostdlib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

I got some errors:

```
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o：In function ‘_start’中：
(.text+0x12)：unresolved reference to ‘__libc_csu_fini’
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o：In function ‘_start’：
(.text+0x19)： unresolved reference to ‘__libc_csu_init’
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o：In function ‘_start’：
(.text+0x25)： unresolved reference to ‘__libc_start_main’
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was trying to see how gcc deals with all necessary object files and try to do it manually. How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fix it?

You are missing `libc` symbols, so you need to link `libc`:

```
gcc test.c -nostdlib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o -lc
```

Bear in mind that if you *really* want to link something "manually", you will do it with `ld`, not `gcc`